# Which LaTeX classes are most widely used for scholarly articles?

Tags: document-classes, big-list

Which LaTeX classes for articles are widely used for preprints (e.g., ArXiv) or journal submissions?

To avoid a huge list of class files, only include publisher's properietary class if they are used in journals outside their stable.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answerable question really. Most journal and conference proceedings that accept latex submission would, I would expect, have a specific class. So such a list is not useful to the author who in each case has only one possible class to use for that publication.

Comment: [London mathematical society](http://www.lms.ac.uk/publications/au-instructions#lmscls),   [Edinburgh mathematical society](http://www.icms.org.uk/assets/files/downloads/EMSpublic.cls), [iciam uses ieeetran](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/?lang=en) ......

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since it is a big-list question and there are a number of Latex class files that are widely used not just by the journal for whom they were prepared (e.g., LLNCS, Revtex) I think this question can be useful, provided it is not spammed by the class files for obscure journals.

Comment: This question should be community wiki, though.

Comment: @CharlesStewart but what's an obscure journal? Do we have to start impact rating journals? Anyway I've voted to close (big-list questions generally don't work well on this site) but its a democratic process, we'll see:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle big-list questions are hit or miss, but some of our most popular questions take this form, e.g., the Latex IDE question has proven a good shopper's guide, I think.  We should give this question a chance.  If it is closed, I will vote to reopen.  We can let downvoting deal with obviously obscure class files.

Comment: @CharlesStewart big-list questions are something that has been discouraged for some years now, for a reason. The old ones survive, but the new ones are rarely good. The old ones are good only because we decided so, at least to me it seems like that. I see no reason why to leave this particular question open.

Comment: @CharlesStewart I can not see how this question can ever be useful, unlike picking an IDE there is rarely any choice here. You have to use the specified class if submitting to a conference. Of the three answers that have been added so far none of them are specifically for mathematics as asked in the question, computer science and physics are clearly related disciplines but it is a big stretch to call LNCS a "mathematics preprint or journal" submission class. (See second comment above for some classes which _are_ used for math journals.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Both mathematical physics and many subdisciplines of theoretical computer science are usually regarded as part of mathematics, and the 3 styles I used are therefore used in mathematics paper, although I think this question would work better if its scope was expanded to cover all academic class files.  yo' disagrees with this (in chat).

Answer (score 1):

[Springer's LLNCS class](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0) is widely used in computer science, including theoretical computer science, which is sort of a branch of mathematics.

Comment: The class itself does not feature modern enhancements such as microtype. I collected the most common packages and cominbed it into a ready-to-run template at https://latextemplates.github.io/LNCS/.

Answer (score 1):

[The RevTeX class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/) is used by many physicists, including mathematical physicists.

Answer (score 1):

[The IEEE's IEEEtran class](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html) is widely used in electrical engineering and computer science, including theoretical computer science which is sort of a branch of mathematics, and it is also used by ICIAM.

Comment: There is still the "compsoc" and "compsocconf" confustion. "compsocconf" was never released officially. It was a hack by some conference organizers and it is still around. I mailed with Michael Shell and he never had that flag. Only "compsoc" and "conference". I have a showcase at a site online, where I also provide a starting template including modern packages such as "microtype". See The class itself does not feature modern enhancements such as microtype. I collected the most common packages and cominbed it into a ready-to-run template at https://latextemplates.github.io/IEEE